# Facebookism in flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

What are magic `$Facebookism`-types in [flow](https://flow.org/en/) and how can I use them?

There are 5 such types in flow repo:

https://github.com/facebook/flow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%24Facebookism&type=

```
declare var idx: $Facebookism$Idx;
declare var merge: $Facebookism$Merge;
declare var mergeDeepInto: $Facebookism$MergeDeepInto;
declare var mergeInto: $Facebookism$MergeInto;
declare var mixin: $Facebookism$Mixin;
```

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/742040/178988)

Comment: Tag selection: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359074/4928642

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `typeof idx` to use the `$Facebookism$Idx` type.

**Original answer:**

> The `$Facebookism` types aren't exported, so I'm afraid you need to
>   declare them yourself for your own code.

Comment: They can be used. At least I know what `idx` is. And it is in its own npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/idx

Comment: @Qwertiy Updated my answer 

Comment: Seems like there is no need to declare them (types, not variables) as they are hardcoded somewhere in flow. But the question was what these types allow to do.